# I would like that as soon as we meet three consecutive True or less (1 or 2) in a list, they are replaced by False

Tags: python, list

I would like that as soon as we meet three consecutive True or less (1 or 2) in a list, they are replaced by False. Would you please know how to do this?
For example :

alist = [True,True,True,False,False,True,True,False,False,True,True,True,True,True,False,True,True,True,True]

The input is =
[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,True,True,False,False,False,False,True]

This code below only works for three True consecutive.

```
alist = [True,True,True,False,False,True,True,False,False,True,True,True,True,True,False,True,True,True,True]
tmp= []
count = 0 # counter for consecutive values of True 
for ind,val in enumerate(alist) :
    if val is False:
        tmp.append(val) # add ele to the temporary list
        count=0 # reset the counter of consecutive values of True
    else :
        tmp.append(val)
        count+=1 
    if count == 3: # if this is the 4th (or bigger) value of True
        k = ind - 2
        for j in range(k,ind+1):
            tmp[j] = False
        count = 0
        
alist=tmp # assign the temporary list to the variable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed your code a bit. Set the `count` to 0 when you get a `False`. If you get a `True` increment the `count` and if `count <= 3` push `False` in the list otherwise push `True`.

```
alist = ([True,True,True,False,False,True,True,False,False,
          True,True,True,True,True,False,True,True,True,True])
tmp= []
count = 0 # counter for consecutive values of True 
for val in alist :
    count = count * val + val
    if count <= 3:
        tmp.append(False)
    else: 
        tmp.append(True)
    
alist=tmp
```